# d3-tip - problems with creating a title in a tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I've successfully created a chart in a tooltip, by following this example: https://bl.ocks.org/maelafifi/ee7fecf90bb5060d5f9a7551271f4397. But my problem is in creating a title, like so:

```
var tool_tip = d3.tip()
            .attr("class", "d3-tip")
            .offset([10, -50])
            .html(function(d){console.log(d); return "<p> Day: and hour:</p><div id='tipDiv'></div>";});
            //.html(function(d,i){console.log(d); return "<p>Distribution for all weeks at: Day: " + d.day + " and hour: " + d.hour +"</p><div id='tipDiv'></div>";}); 
            svg_sum.call(tool_tip);
```

I actually want to create the text that is commented out, but when looking in the console, it says that d is undefined. Additionally, I would like to use the information in d to offset the tooltip. My attempt can be seen here: http://bl.ocks.org/skov94/0c4befd23bcaeacb85c18c7a5484f95d

Comment: Minor change: Pass `d` while calling `tool_tip.show` i.e. `tool_tip.show(d)` and it'll work.

Comment: Ohh, of course - thank you very much :)

Comment: Sure. No problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have an argument `d` which you might have forgotten to pass in.

So, when calling the function, do something like:

`tool_tip.show(day)`